Through which immigration checkpoints must one go if crossing the Darien gap legally?
Assume one crosses the Darien gap and wants to properly do the immigration process. Through which immigration checkpoints must one go? Assume the traveler is a French citizen (which grants them visa-free entry to Panama and Colombia). I'm interested in both directions of the crossing, eg from Panama to Colombia and vice-versa.

Related: Are French citizens banned by their government from entering the Darian gap, or do they need authorization by the French gov to enter the Darian gap?

From Wiki: "In 2023, more than 520,000 passed through the gap, more than doubling the previous year's number of crossings". Doesn't seem to be that isolated any longer :-)

JonathanReez point to these stats from wikipedia.org:

In 2022, there were 250,000 crossings, compared to only 24,000 in 2019.[14] In 2023, more than 520,000 passed through the gap, more than doubling the previous year's number of crossings.[9]


Travel advice from governments, discouraging their citizens to travel to certain areas, are not 'travel bans' or situations where permission must be granted.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Immigration checkpoints will likely be one of the least of your concerns. All other things considered you will likely present yourself in a migration office before and after crossing the gap (maybe Turbo in Colombia and Puerto Obaldia in Panama).
Likely no one will check your passport during the cross, save by maybe some criminals who won't require you to have a specific stamp.

...and may want to keep your passport in exchange for some disproportionate payment.

I have downvoted this answer because it does not answer the question.

I think this answers the question pretty well.

@littleadv the response to the question is "I'm not exactly sure how this is done" -- that is not an answer

@ajd given that there are no checkpoints in the gap, going to the nearest one outside the gap is a proper answer. Even the most likely ones to go to are mentioned.

Some online sources indicate that perhaps advance permission is needed to alert the border forces that you will be coming through. A better answer to this question is possible. (How far in advance? Who exactly to contact?)
